# A simple Quiz in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a python code to drill a user in english and fresh, depending on the option , it would ask either english or french questions and accept answers, it would then check the inputted answers against a list and increment the score, however after the first question, my code stops running

I have tried including a for loop and making the while loop part of the function 
yet nothing

```
#Python program to drill a student in french
import sys
option = 0
score=0
english_questions=['What is Thank you in French___?', 'What is you are welcome in French___?', 'What is no in French___?', 'What is Pardon in French___?', 'What is yes in French?___?']
french_questions =['What does Merci mean in English___? ', 'What does derien mean in English___?','What does No mean in English___?', 'What does pardon mean in English___?', 'What does oui mean in English___?' ]
french_answers =['merci', 'derien', 'no', 'pardon', 'oui']
english_answers=['thankyou', 'welcome', 'no', 'pardon', 'yes']
number_of_questions = 5
question_number = 0
print('Welcome to English-French Vocabulary Drill')
print('*********************************************')
print('To be drilled in English Press 1')
print('To be drilled in French Press 2')
print('*********************************************')

#a try except block to handle invalid option type
if option not in (1, 2):
     try:
         option=input('Please Enter option:')
     except:
         print('Invalid option, Please enter 1 or 2')

if option == 1:
   questions = english_questions
   answers = french_answers
elif option == 2:
    questions = french_questions
    answers = english_answers
#Function to check answer
def check_answer(user_answer, questions, answers):
    if user_answer in answers:
        print('')
        print('Correct')
        global score
        score +=1 
        global question_number
        question_number +=1
    else:
        print('')
        print('Incorrect, try again')
        global guesses 
        guesses +=1

global number_of_questions
while question_number < number_of_questions: 
    x = questions[question_number]
    user_answer = answers[question_number]
    print('')
    user_answer = input (x + ':')
    print (check_answer(user_answer, x, answers))
    print('')
    print('score : ' +str(score) )
```

I expected it to print out each of the questions and request answers one after the other but what I get is "Correct None score : 0 W:"

Comment: Please format your code. You can convert an entire section to code by enclosing it in backticks, ie:

\`\`\`
the code
\`\`\`

will produce ```the code```

Comment: would do that now

Comment: you do realize the `try/except` is useless as you are not checking for anything. You are simply taking an input so that will never raise an Exception except for KeyboardInterrupt...

Comment: Also, this `if option!= 1 or 2 and type(option) == int:` will always be true. change to: `if option not in (1, 2) and type(option) == int:`

Comment: You are not checking for any other value. E.g. i entered 4 as an input and it directly went to while ` question_number < number_of_questions` therefore giving error NameError: name 'questions' is not defined

Comment: OP, the scope of your question has changed each time you have edited it. By the time someone writes an answer, the question has changed.

Answer (score 0):

Here: `questions = questions[question_number]`, you're assigning to `questions` a value of the `questions` list. When the loop is executed a second time, you'll have a letter, as you'll ask the program to find `questions[question_number][question_number]`. Perhaps you should try using different variable names?

Comment: i sincerely do not understand

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Rasgel's answer, you should change all your `a =+ b` statements to `a += b` for proper incrementing.

Comment: my score counter now works , and it terminates after 5 questions . but it keeps asking the first question over and over

Answer (score 0):

I have somewhat corrected the code. There were many mistakes.

- you need to make global variables which are being used everywhere in code like score and 
  guesses
- you need to store questions[question_number] in a new variable.
- you need to add while loop to check for incorrect inputs.

```
import sys


score  = 0
guesses= 0

english_questions=['What is Thank you in French___?', 'What is you are welcome in French___?', 'What is no in French___?', 'What is Pardon in French___?', 'What is yes in French?___?']
french_questions =['What does Merci mean in English___? ', 'What does derien mean in English___?','What does No mean in English___?', 'What does pardon mean in English___?', 'What does oui mean in English___?' ]
french_answers =['merci', 'derien', 'no', 'pardon', 'oui']
english_answers=['thankyou', 'welcome', 'no', 'pardon', 'yes']

number_of_questions = 5

question_number = 0

print('Welcome to English-French Vocabulary Drill')

print('*********************************************')
print('To be drilled in English Press 1')
print('To be drilled in French Press 2')
print('*********************************************')

#a try except block to handle invalid option type
option= int(input('Please Enter option:'))
while option not in (1,2) and type(option) == int:
   option = int(input("please enter valid option"))

if option == 1:
   questions = english_questions
   answers = french_answers
elif option == 2:
   questions = french_questions
   answers = english_answers

#Function to check answer

def check_answer(user_answer, answers):
   global question_number
   if user_answer in answers:
       print('')
       print('Correct')
       global score
       score += 1


   else:
       print('')
       print('Incorrect, try again')
       global guesses

       guesses = guesses+ 1
   question_number = question_number + 1

while question_number < number_of_questions: 
   cur_question = questions[question_number]
   user_answer = answers[question_number]
   print('')
   user_answer = input (cur_question + ':')
   print (check_answer(user_answer, answers))
   print('')

print('score : ' +str(score) )
```

Comment: thanks, i figured out the global declaration , my only issue now is it keeps repeating the same questions over and over

Comment: did you copy my code? it doesn't ask the same question in mine.

Comment: Your code has a syntax error on line 26 (I guess indentation didn't survive the transfer) but generally speaking, it's best not to rewrite the code for a user, rather point them to specific mistakes.

Comment: fixed mine, i have one last error, it shows none, after correct

Comment: replace `print (check_answer(user_answer, answers))` with `check_answer(user_answer, answers)`

Answer (score 0):

Declare and initialize these variables at the top of the script:

```
number_of_questions = 0
guesses = 0
```

Then compare options against strings, it's a user input:

```
if option == '1':
    questions = english_questions
    answers = french_answers
elif option == '2':
    questions = french_questions
    answers = english_answers
```

With these fixes it runs without raising.